# Javascript Plugin for Office/Outlook using HTA?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

Is HTA a good way to write a plug-in for Outlook using JavaScript?

I would like to reuse most of my existing JavaScript code from a Chrome Extension and have only few system specific code to maintain. What would be the best way to develop a JavaScript based plug-in for the windows world and the web world.

The plug-in should integrate into the Outlook emails (context menu / ribbon) and send or query information via REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about the new way to do it with javascript: [msdn javascript apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220060.aspx)

It only works for 2013 but this should be Ok.

Comment: And only if the user uses Exchange 2013 Server. Which makes it useless. You don't really have a choice other than writing a regular COM add-in - see http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36

Comment: Thank you for this advice. Outlook Apps require Exchange 2013 as stated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220082.aspx#StartBuildingApps_Requirements. Ok but is there any way to use javascript together with the COM addin?

Comment: Not directly. You can implement IActiveScriptSite, IActiveScriptSiteWindow, IActiveScriptSiteDebug interfaces to run any VB or JavaScript code, but I don't know if .Net would let you do that.